# How to approach the negative root of the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma_1(k) x^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots, divisor-sum

Let's define
$$
f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma_1(k) x^k, \quad \text{where } \sigma_1(k) = \sum\limits_{d|k}d
$$

Is there a way to approach the root $x_0$ of this series, where $-1 < x_0 < 0$ ? I tried to squeeze it and using geometric series, but its too far away.

Comment: Worth noting: if instead of exponentials you had powers, the result is a known Dirichlet series, namely $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma_1(k) k^x = \zeta(-x)\zeta(-1-x)$.

Comment: Another form of $f(x)$ is $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n\frac{{x^n }}{{1 - x^n }}} .
$$

Comment: I got $x=-0.4112485$ with an error less than $10^{-7}$

Comment: This is essentially the Eisenstein series $E_2$.  See (11) at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EisensteinSeries.html ... Unlike $E_4, E_6, \dots$, the series $E_2$ is not modular, so many methods of evaluation are not available.

Comment: @GEdgar: Anyway, with $E_2(\tau)=1-24f(e^{2i\pi\tau})$, we have $E_2(-1/\tau)=\tau^2 E_2(\tau)+6\tau/(i\pi)$, and it is pretty good here; if $\tau$ corresponds to $|x_0|\approx 0.411$, then $-1/\tau$ corresponds to something like $\approx 0.037$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I truncated the sum at $n$ terms and applied three iterations of Newton's Method, starting at $x_0=-0.5$. Here are the results:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 2 & -0.333384146341463 \\
 3 & 0.0961538461538462 \\
 4 & -0.397485670060330 \\
 5 & -0.500000000000000 \\
 6 & -0.407129807891880 \\
 7 & -0.420277540201558 \\
 8 & -0.409817509129324 \\
 9 & -0.413179097089750 \\
 10 & -0.411220988091159 \\
 11 & -0.411739696601906 \\
 12 & -0.411245203711637 \\
 13 & -0.411344738057402 \\
 14 & -0.411275353266776 \\
 15 & -0.411303377636828 \\
 16 & -0.411288790446980 \\
 17 & -0.411292174341874 \\
 18 & -0.411289268468018 \\
 19 & -0.411289851523367 \\
 20 & -0.411289380413744 \\
 21 & -0.411289515069802 \\
 22 & -0.411289460359527 \\
 23 & -0.411289472717242 \\
 24 & -0.411289463450467 \\
 25 & -0.411289464495063 \\
 26 & -0.411289464563588 \\
 27 & -0.411289464215141 \\
 28 & -0.411289464649207 \\
 29 & -0.411289464488793 \\
 30 & -0.411289464727583 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$ Based on this, I would say with high certainty that the root satisfies $x_0\approx -0.41128946$.

Comment: Only 4 digits are correct, as I found $-0.411248$ with an error less than $10^{-7}$

Comment: Is Newton's Method secure here? I stayed away from Newton's Method because I feared the "jumping around" in a fractal way.

Comment: @Raffaele after entering $-1/2$ and rounding afterwards, I obtained much greater accuracy with the same method

Comment: @thinkingeye NM is probably fine because the polynomial doesn't grow too quickly. A *very* coarse bound on the terms is $(k+k(k+2)/8)$: the sum up to $k/2$ plus $k$. For $x\approx -0.5$, these terms mean the derivative is bounded by $1$ in some neighborhood of the root; this will give us convergence (speaking fast and loose here).

Comment: @Integrand Newton's method needs derivative. How did you get it?

Comment: @Raffaele I'm working with the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sigma_1(k)x^k$.

Comment: @Integrand Me too, but I got $x=-0.411248479177954$ with an error less than $10^{-15}$

Comment: @Raffaele if you want to justify this by posting your own answer or explaining your method, I look forward to reading it.

Comment: Maybe it needs more than 3 NM iterations for higher precision. By the way, interrestingly the decimals are on oeis as: http://oeis.org/A143441

Comment: @thinkingeye Amazing! Read the "bonus" section of my answer

Answer (score 3):

With the help of *Mathematica* I defined
$$f(x)=\sum _{k=1}^{1000} \sigma _1(k) x^k$$
then  I applied the Newton's method starting from $x_0=-0.411248$

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

$$
\begin{array}{r|l}
n   &x_n\\
\hline
0 &-0.411248\\
1 &-0.4112484791789996\\
2 &-0.4112484791779548\\
3 &-0.4112484791779548\\
4 &-0.4112484791779547\\
5 &-0.4112484791779548\\
\end{array}
$$

bonus

Define Pochhammer symbol
$$Poch(q)=\prod _{k=0}^{\infty } \left(1-q^{k+1}\right)$$
The root of $Poch'(q)$ in the interval $(-1,0)$ is the same as the root of $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma _1(k) x^k$ in the same interval.

Comment: With respect, I prefer my setup for two reasons. 1) Surely you will get greater accuracy using a higher-degree polynomial, but it is more computationally intensive as well. The fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \operatorname{poly}(n)x^n=0$ for $|x|<1$ means you have diminishing returns for going all the way out to $n=1000$. 2) Your initial guess isn't 'random': it's much closer to the value of the root, but it involves some knowledge of the root *a priori*. Especially if you are doing any of this 'by hand', $-1/2$ is a simpler and more egalitarian starting point.

Comment: @Integrand This is not a competition. I used the first result of NM as input of a second application to fasten the iteration. The link with the Pochhammer symbol is amazing, tho